# Center a circle in the middle of a div

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to have this situation by using bootstrap:

[image: myImage]

So, basically I'd like to have the circle in the middle of that gray div.

I wrote this code, but I can't figured out what I'm wrong.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="row" style="margin: unset; width: 100%">
       <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #E5E5E5; height: 46px; 
          line-height: 46px; text-align: center; opacity: 100%">
            <div class="numberCircleInOut"> 124 </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-11" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; height:46px; 
         line-height: 46px"> Motion timeout 
       </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.numberCircleInOut {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #484848;
  color: #484848;
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add this code in your css.

`margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center` for `col-md-1` or CSS Change

```
.numberCircleInOut {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #484848;
  color: #484848;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
 }

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin: unset; width: 100%">
<div class="col-md-1 py-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #E5E5E5;">
    <div class="numberCircleInOut"> 124 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-11" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
    Motion timeout
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/j3axm9f6/9/

Answer (score 0):

In order to align horizontally a div you can use `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`. Or you could just use `margin: 0 auto 0 auto`. Remember that `margin` sets top, right, bottom and left in that order.

```css
.numberCircleInOut {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #484848;
  color: #484848;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="row" style="margin: unset; width: 100%">
       <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #E5E5E5; height: 46px; 
          line-height: 46px; text-align: center; opacity: 100%">
            <div class="numberCircleInOut"> 124 </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-11" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; height:46px; 
         line-height: 46px"> Motion timeout 
       </div>
  </div>
```